# Most Mac Mini like PC

Tags: mac

Does anyone know if it would be possible to build a PC with the form factor of a mac mini? small and quiet

Comment: You should go onto www.newegg.com. You're able to browse their hardware and different items based on your criteria. You can see pictures and get a feel of what your looking at.

Comment: The answer to your question is: Yes.

Answer (score 0):

From a pdf that I downloaded quite a while back,

Logic Supply 3688 mini-ITX System

- Power Supply Morex 60 Watt Power Supply
- Operating System Windows XP Home - English
- Motherboard EPIA MII 12000 1.2Ghz
- Memory 256MB PC2100/DDR266 RAM
- Hard Disk 2.5" 40GB Seagate 5400rpm
- Color Silver
- CD / DVD Drive Panasonic CW-8123-B Slotloading CD-RW / DVD
- Build and test this system

Total: $710 
Original author:Jason Sares  
Disclamer from the author: The final system is still a little bigger, slower and more expensive than the `Mac Mini` itself

Comment: quite a while back eh? sounds like it was from 10 years ago :)

Comment: There you go, found the original article: http://macmini.blogspot.com/2005/01/windows-mini-build-challenge.html ... @kobaltz, 2005 :)

Comment: :) yea, now a days, $710 wound get you a pretty sweet setup.